How do I incorporate a row into a GROUP BY query in MySQL?
I have a table for recording the mark a student got in a subject on a particular date. The table, perf, has columns id,date,student,subject,mark.
Objective: I want to compare the mark obtained by a student against the highest, the lowest and the average class mark in a particular subject for each day using a single query such as:
SELECT date,mark,highest,lowest,avg,student FROM ....   

.... and get this result:



date
mark
highest
lowest
avg
student




2021-09-07
73
82
58
69
2c3


2021-09-09
81
84
62
75
2c3


2021-09-14
78
78
68
73
2c3


2021-09-17
75
89
59
73
2c3



How do I achieve my objective in a single statement?
I am open to intermediate steps, eg, creating views.
I am using MySQL 8.0.33.
Here is the data:



id
date
student
subject
mark




1
2021-09-6
a1b
English
78


2
2021-09-7
a1b
Art
63


3
2021-09-8
a1b
Math
67


4
2021-09-09
a1b
Art
71


5
2021-09-09
a1b
English
74


6
2021-09-10
a1b
Math
65


7
2021-09-13
a1b
English
81


8
2021-09-14
a1b
Art
68


9
2021-09-15
a1b
Math
70


10
2021-09-16
a1b
English
79


11
2021-09-17
a1b
Art
70


12
2021-09-17
a1b
Math
68


14
2021-09-6
2c3
English
68


15
2021-09-7
2c3
Art
73


16
2021-09-8
2c3
Math
57


17
2021-09-09
2c3
Art
81


18
2021-09-09
2c3
English
74


19
2021-09-10
2c3
Math
55


20
2021-09-13
2c3
English
73


21
2021-09-14
2c3
Art
78


22
2021-09-15
2c3
Math
60


23
2021-09-16
2c3
English
71


24
2021-09-17
2c3
Art
75


25
2021-09-17
2c3
Math
58


26
2021-09-6
3d4
English
53


27
2021-09-7
3d4
Art
58


28
2021-09-8
3d4
Math
56


29
2021-09-09
3d4
Art
62


30
2021-09-09
3d4
English
54


31
2021-09-10
3d4
Math
51


32
2021-09-13
3d4
English
51


33
2021-09-14
3d4
Art
68


34
2021-09-15
3d4
Math
60


35
2021-09-16
3d4
English
58


36
2021-09-17
3d4
Art
59


37
2021-09-17
3d4
Math
58


38
2021-09-6
4ef
English
87


39
2021-09-7
4ef
Art
82


40
2021-09-8
4ef
Math
91


41
2021-09-09
4ef
Art
84


42
2021-09-09
4ef
English
79


43
2021-09-10
4ef
Math
81


44
2021-09-13
4ef
English
73


45
2021-09-14
4ef
Art
78


46
2021-09-15
4ef
Math
82


47
2021-09-16
4ef
English
82


48
2021-09-17
4ef
Art
89


49
2021-09-17
4ef
Math
92



I am able to get the highest, lowest, average class mark using GROUP BY as follows:
SELECT date,subject,MAX(mark) AS highest, MIN(mark) AS lowest, FORMAT(AVG(mark),0) AS avg FROM perf GROUP BY date,subject   




date
mark
highest
lowest
avg




2021-09-06
English
87
53
72


2021-09-07
Art
82
58
69


2021-09-08
Math
91
56
68


2021-09-09
Art
84
62
75


2021-09-09
English
79
54
70


2021-09-10
Math
81
51
63



On trying to incorporate mark and student into the above query gives senseless results:
SELECT date,subject,mark,MAX(mark) AS highest, MIN(mark) AS lowest, FORMAT(AVG(mark),0) AS avg,student FROM perf GROUP BY date,subject,mark,student  




date
subject
mark
highest
lowest
avg
student




2021-09-16
English
71
71
71
71
2c3


2021-09-07
Art
73
73
73
73
2c3


2021-09-13
English
73
73
73
73
2c3


2021-09-13
English
73
73
73
73
4ef


2021-09-09
English
74
74
74
74
a1b


2021-09-09
English
74
74
74
74
2c3


2021-09-17
Art
75
75
75
75
2c3


2021-09-06
English
78
78
78
78
a1b



I tried several things but have only been successful in combining mark,highest,lowest,avg,student in a single result when I specify student,subject and date as follows, but that's too specific and not what I want:
SELECT (SELECT date FROM perf WHERE student='2c3' AND subject='Art' AND date='2021-09-07') AS date,  
(SELECT mark FROM perf WHERE student='2c3' AND subject='Art' AND date='2021-09-07') AS mark,  
(SELECT MAX(mark) FROM perf WHERE subject='Art' AND date='2021-09-07') AS highest,  
(SELECT MIN(mark) FROM perf WHERE subject='Art' AND date='2021-09-07') AS lowest,  
(SELECT FORMAT(AVG(mark),0) FROM perf WHERE subject='Art' AND date='2021-09-07') AS avg 




date
mark
highest
lowest
avg




2021-09-07
73
82
58
69




Please [edit] your question and make an effort to format it so that it's readable. Your SQL statements should be formatted as code, and your data should be in tables. You can get formatting help by clicking the ? in the toolbar while making that edit.

SELECT
a.DATE,
b.lowest,
b.highest,
b.avg,
a.student,
a.mark
FROM perf a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
DATE,
SUBJECT, 
MIN(mark) AS lowest,
MAX(mark) AS highest,
AVG(mark) AS AVG
FROM perf
GROUP BY DATE,SUBJECT ) b ON a.date = b.date AND a.subject = b.subject


Works perfect. Thanks.


Proof of Work GitHub Input and Output from SQL Online Compiler: https://gist.github.com/xentzenith/ccdcc3e11f377195645cf2db8a4dccf0
To achieve your objective of comparing the mark obtained by a student against the highest, lowest, and average class marks in a particular subject for each day, you can use a combination of window functions and subqueries.
WITH stats AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        subject,
        MAX(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY date, subject) AS highest,
        MIN(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY date, subject) AS lowest,
        AVG(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY date, subject) AS avg
    FROM perf
)
SELECT
    p.date,
    p.mark,
    s.highest,
    s.lowest,
    ROUND(s.avg, 0) AS avg,
    p.student
FROM perf p
JOIN stats s ON p.date = s.date AND p.subject = s.subject
WHERE p.mark = s.mark;

The stats CTE computes the highest, lowest, and average marks for each subject on each date using window functions (MAX(), MIN(), AVG()). The PARTITION BY clause specifies the group of rows for which the aggregate function is applied. It should work for you if you are using appropriate SQL version :)

Gives error 1054 - Unknown column 's.mark' in 'where clause'. Removing the line "WHERE p.mark = s.mark" clears the error.
However, the resulting solution returns duplicate rows. Changing "SELECT date, subject, ..." to "SELECT DISTINCT date, subject, ..." removes the duplicates.
Apparently the solution on your GitHub does not give the give error 1054, though it still returns duplicates.

Use a CTE to calculate the overall values and join to that:
with cte as (
  SELECT
    date,
    subject,
    MAX(mark) AS highest,
    MIN(mark) AS lowest,
    FORMAT(AVG(c.mark), 0) AS avg
  FROM perf
  GROUP BY date, subject  
)
SELECT
    c.date,
    c.subject,
    p.mark,
    c.highest,
    c.lowest,
    c.avg,
    p.student
FROM perf p
JOIN cte c ON c.date = p.date
  AND c.subject = p.subject


Thanks
Gives error 1054 - Unknown column 'c.mark' in 'field list'.
Works fine on changing "c.mark" to "mark" in field list and removing "WHERE c.mark = p.mark"

Maybe u can use mysql8 window function, it can stat data from multiple dimensions in one row.
SELECT 
    p.*,
    MAX(p.mark) over(PARTITION BY p.date, p.subject) AS highest,
    MIN(p.mark) over(PARTITION BY p.date, p.subject) AS lowest,
    format(AVG(p.mark) over(PARTITION BY p.date, p.subject), 0) AS AVG  
FROM perf p 

the result is :



id
date
student
subject
mark
highest
lowest
AVG




1
2021-09-06
a1b
English
78
87
53
72


14
2021-09-06
2c3
English
68
87
53
72


38
2021-09-06
4ef
English
87
87
53
72


26
2021-09-06
3d4
English
53
87
53
72


2
2021-09-07
a1b
Art
63
82
58
69


...










This is a simple usage of window functions. may help u.

Neat. Works perfect. However, execution seems to take twice the time of the solutions presented here so far.
